# Premature EOF error in flex

Tags: apache-flex, eof

When I run the following code in flex , i get premature EOF at the last line as an error. If the definition part is removed no error is generated.Why is this so??

```
%{
     #include <stdio.h>
       int x = 0;
}%

%%
"a"  {x=x+1; printf("id %d",x); }
%%

int yywrap(void)
{
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
int x = 0;
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The third line of your code has the problem . It should be %} instead of }%

Try this :

```
%{
x = 0;
%}

%%
[a]  {x++; printf("id %d",x); }
%%

int main(void)
{
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what you intend to do but a working example that will print an *id* for every *a* encountered in input file will somewhat look like this :

```
%{
x = 0;
%}

%%
[a]  {x++; printf("id %d ",x); }
%%

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
  yyin = fopen(argv[1],"r");
  yylex();
  fclose(yyin);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to return true (1) from yywrap, not 0.

From the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Generated-Scanner.html#index-yywrap_0028_0029):

> When the scanner receives an end-of-file indication from `YY_INPUT`, it then checks the `yywrap()` function.  If `yywrap()` returns false (zero), then it is assumed that the function has gone ahead and set up `yyin` to point to another input file, and scanning continues.  If it returns true (non-zero), then the scanner terminates, returning 0 to its caller.